# How to calculate a geometric cross field inside an arbitrary polygon?

Tags: geometry, field, interpolation

I'm having troubles finding a way to calculate a "cross-field" inside an arbitrary polygon.
A Cross field, as defined by one paper **is the smoothest field that is tangential to the domain boundary (in this case the polygon)** I find it a lot in quad re-topology papers but surprisingly not even in Wikipedia I can find the definition of a Cross field.
I have images but since I'm new here the system said I need at least 10 reputation points to upload images.

Any ideas?
I think it could be something along the lines of an interpolation? given an inner point determine the distance to each edge and integrate or weight sum the tangent and perpendicular vector of every edge by the distance? (or any other factor in fact)
But other simpler approaches may exist?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
//I've come up with something like this (for the 3D case), very raw, educational purposes
float ditance2segment(Vector3D p, Vector3D p0, Vector3D p1){
   Vector3D v = p1 - p0;
   Vector3D w = p - p0;
   float c1 = v.Dot(w);
   if (c1 <= 0)
      return (p - p1).Length();
   float c2 = v.Dot(v);
   if (c2 <= c1)
      return (p - p1).Length();

   float b = c1 / c2;
   Vector3D pb = p0 + b*v;
   return (p - pb).Length();

}
void CrossFieldInterpolation(List<Vector3D>& Contour, List<Vector3D>&   ContourN, Vector3D p, Vector3D& crossU, Vector3D& crossV){
    int N = Contour.Amount();   
    for (int i=0; i < N; i++){
        Vector3D u = Contour[(i + 1) % N] - Contour[i];     
        Vector3D n = 0.5*(ContourN[(i + 1) % N] + ContourN[i]); 
        Vector3D v = -Vector3D::Cross(u,n); //perpendicular vector  
        u = Vector3D::Normalize(u);
        n = Vector3D::Normalize(n);
        v = Vector3D::Normalize(v);

        float dist = ditance2segment(p, Contour[i], Contour[(i+1)%N]);

        crossU += u / (1+dist); //to avoid infinity at points over the segment
        crossV += v / (1+dist);
    }
    crossU = Vector3D::Normalize(crossU);   
    crossV = Vector3D::Normalize(crossV);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the OpenSource Graphite software that I'm developping, it implements the "Periodic Global Parameterization" algorithm [1] that was developed in my research team. You may be also interested in the following research articles with algorithms that we developed more recently [2],[3]

Graphite website:
http://alice.loria.fr/software/graphite

How to use Periodic Global Parameterization:
http://alice.loria.fr/WIKI/index.php/Graphite/PGP

[1] http://alice.loria.fr/index.php/publications.html?Paper=TOG_pgp%402006

[2] http://alice.loria.fr/index.php/publications.html?Paper=DGF@2008

[3] http://alice.loria.fr/index.php/publications.html?redirect=0&Paper=DFD@2008&Author=vallet